# How to get the gradient to stay inside the webpage

Tags: html, css

Hey guys and gals how do I get the gradient to stay inside the webpage?? currently its bleeding off and I don't know how to contain it:

[image: Example]

here is my code I hope you can help

```css
.image {
  display: block;
  width: 10%;
  height: auto;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 1s ease;
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgb(0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
}

.nftpic:hover .overlay {
  opacity: 1;
}

.text {
  color: rgba(110, 109, 109, 0.568);
  font-size: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}

.intro {
  background-image: url("https://i.ibb.co/TRqB4TQ/meagan-carsience-Rez5o-Ghem-Zw-unsplash.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-color: #0a80e0b0;
  color: white;
}

a:hover {
  color: turquoise;
}
```

```html
<div class="nftpic">
  <img src="https://i.ibb.co/R01Lw9J/NFTs-001-A.jpg" alt="" height="100" width="100px" class="center">
  <div class="overlay">
    <div class="text">Welcome to 'The HC Network'</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you want the gradient to overlay the page, or just the image? Regardless, the gradient does not overflow the page based on the code you've provided: there's probably something on the original page that is causing this issue, that you have not shared in your [mcve].

Comment: turns out its something to do with the scaling of an image. Transform: scale(2); seems to be pushing the page off of the intended space allocated. TIA

Comment: I don’t see scaling in the given snippet.